# Is a message broker appropriate for a simple message sender and receiver?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am getting involved with a project that will build, at first, a simple message system that will receive messages, store them and route them to appropriate departments. The basic use case is:

- Person writes a message or a question in a website form and chooses a department to route the message to
- Based on the person's selection, the message gets routed to the proper department's message queue with a status of "unread," "read," etc. (we don't have all of the statuses determined yet).
- These messages become part of a person's interaction with the website, i.e., if they call customer service, they will be able to pull up the messages that person has sent and received

The basic question is whether or not a message broker is justifiable in this scenario. I can see arguments for and against. First, simply writing messages to the database risks timeouts, deadlocks and such that could lose messages. Code would need to take care of these scenarios. A message broker, such as RabbitMQ, could process messages and save them regardless of whether the databases or systems are up and running and so lessen message loss.

On the other hand, a message broker also seems like overkill because it's simply passing messages to one or more departments and then disappearing into a person's history. So why include all of that infrastructure for something so simple?

This system will get built upon from this initial framework, so it won't remain a simple message sender, but as of now it will not connect applications or systems together nor does it seem to be providing anything like ESB functionality. Right now, the plan is to use RabbitMQ, MassTransit and Sagas to send, route and track messages. Is this too much? Or is it warranted since we aim for a 0% failure rate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand the architecture of this system.  Are you using message queues just because you have the domain object of a "message"?  Is there something about these messages that actually needs to be "delivered"?  Are they heterogeneous systems that are going to be receiving these messages?  Or some offline processing that needs to occur?

You look to have a simple database table of "messages" that have statuses, departments, and content unless you are doing something with those messages, you are putting way too much infrastructure in place.

Comment: Hello, the messages will get routed to various departments based on the selection made by the person initiating the message, but it seems like this might be able to be handled by database or some mechanism other than a message broker. Based on your answer, I'm thinking this system may be overdoing it in terms of infrastructure, which is exactly the question I'm trying to answer. Would this system just be fine using database calls? There seems to be 1 system at this point that will route the messages - no calls to other microservices, etc.

Comment: Yes, until "department" means another piece of software, don't use a messaging system.

Comment: Would this be best implemented with straight database calls then?

Comment: Sure, unless you need some asynchronous processing, or explicitly need to decouple the operations.